# React native multi-language issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, internationalization, multilingual

I have small react native app where I'm trying to implement multi-language that reload components in real time when I change language.

I'm using react-native-i18n library. I have my Language component and here is the code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { selected: 'sr_ME' };
}

async componentDidMount() {
  let currentLanguage = await this.getLocalKey('lang', 'sr_ME');
  this.setState({ selected: currentLanguage });
}

getLocalKey = async (key, defaultValue) => {
  try {
    let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    return value != null ? value : defaultValue;
  } catch (e) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
}

storeLocalKey = async (key, value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
  } catch (e) { 
    // handle error if necessary...
  }
};

onValueChange(value) {
  I18n.locale = value; 
  this.setState({ selected: value }, () => this.storeLocalKey('lang', value));
  this.props.updateParentState({ 'lang': value });
}
...
```

The component above I'm importing on another screen like this:

```
static navigationOptions = {
  header: null
};

state = {};

updateState(data) {
  I18n.locale = data.lang;
}

render() {
   return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Header style={styles.header}>
          <Left>
            <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>{I18n.t('home')}</Text>
          </Left>
          <Right>
            <LanguageButton updateParentState={this.updateState.bind(this)}/>
          </Right>
        </Header>
      </Container>);
    }
```

I'm trying to achieve that every change of language in Language component updates the locale and reloads the parent component and apply language to other components too.

This, for now, only translates title in navigation header but content stay unchanged.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following npm [react-native-localization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-localization) for multilingual application. You can define multiple languages into a string js file.

```
 // ES6 module syntax

import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';

let strings = new LocalizedStrings({

 en:{

   how:"How do you want your egg today?",

   boiledEgg:"Boiled egg",

  softBoiledEgg:"Soft-boiled egg",

   choice:"How to choose the egg"

 },

 it: {

   how:"Come vuoi il tuo uovo oggi?",

   boiledEgg:"Uovo sodo",

   softBoiledEgg:"Uovo alla coque",

   choice:"Come scegliere l'uovo"

 }

});
```

For change language, you can use this function on your code form where you want to change the language
force a particular language use something like this:

```
 import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';

_onSetLanguageToItalian() {

 strings.setLanguage('it');

  this.setState({});

RNRestart.Restart()

}
```

[react-native-restart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-restart) npm is used to restart the app and reflect language change into the whole app

Comment: now I'm getting the following error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeRestart.default.Restart'). This happened when I called the .Restart() function.

Comment: Do you linked and import react native restart npm properly??? Please try to use previous version of this package it may be help react-native-restart@0.0.5

Comment: I have tried with lower version but still the same error.

Comment: Please check following link it will help to solve this issue https://github.com/avishayil/react-native-restart

Comment: I've already checked that link. I have different folder structure... and I don't have react-native command.

Comment: Use **Util.reload()** in expo it will help to restart app and for more information please check once expo api document please check this example also https://snack.expo.io/Sy6SpHgGz                                change view direction please use this codeI18nManager.allowRTL(false);
I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
.....
Then use  Expo.Util.reload() or Util.reload()