# Switch Language inside the app using redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, localization

I have been trying to keep multi language option in react native application, by which user can select language when they first uses the app and also they can change language using settings menu ( a special radio button screen to select language ).

I have checked various libraries, like react-native-localize, react-native-languages but i think none supports switching the language inside the app.

So far, i have used I18n.js library to achieve translation. This is my code of I18n.js:

```
  import I18n from "i18n-js";
  import en from "./locales/en";
  import tm from "./locales/tm";

  I18n.fallbacks = true;
  I18n.defaultLocale = 'tm';
  I18n.locale = 'tm';
  I18n.translations = {
   en,
   tm
  };

  export default I18n;
```

And language changes, correctly when "I18n.defaultLocale = 'tm'" changes. But how to achieve the switch function. I thought of using redux, but as above code isnt react component i couldnt connect this with redux.

Please guide me to solve this !

How to effectively change `I18n.defaultLocale = 'tm'` inside this file "I18n.js". Whats the ways to do this ?

Comment: Facing same issues !

Comment: Please check this it may help to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071189/react-native-multi-language-issue/55085258#55085258